# How to install Avant Window Navigator

Tags: software-installation, python

Complete Linux noob here. I'm learning things by having just having a go at things. I'm currently exploring customising the desktop and I'm trying to install Avant Window Navigator.

I've downloaded the file and have unpacked it and read the README - not that it made much sense.

`The following packages are required to build Awn from source. Note that in most
distributions, you need both the library and development/header packages
installed in order for the build process to work correctly.

- GNU Make
- libdesktop-agnostic [1]_
- libwnck 2.22 or later
- libX11
- dbus-glib
- xdamage
- xcomposite
- xrender
- Python 2.5 or later
- PyGTK 2.12 or later
- pyxdg (also known as python-xdg)`

I don't really know what a package is, or a library or a development/header package - but decided to give it a try anyway.

I went to the directory in the terminal and did `./configure` and got the following message at the end

`configure: error: 
  Could not link test program to Python. Maybe the main Python library has been
  installed in some non-standard library path. If so, pass it to configure,
  via the LDFLAGS environment variable.
  Example: ./configure LDFLAGS="-L/usr/non-standard-path/python/lib"
  ============================================================================
   ERROR!
   You probably have to install the development version of the Python package
   for your distribution.  The exact name of this package varies among them.`

It sounds like I need to install python, but when I tried `sudo apt-get install python` it says version 2.7.15 is already installed, and this is a recent enough version. So does this mean it is in a non standard library path? How would I find out?

And how do I check for all the other things in the required packages list?

Thanks

Comment: Haven't read all yet first wanted to know what was this program. Now I know and just wanted to know why you want to install this if you have plank in elementary. I'll keep reading your question now :P

Answer (score 1):

After reading about the project I don't recommend you to install this. Is too old and hasn't been active for years.

If you still want to install it, I could hep you with your errors but probably you'll find plenty.

---

The development package of `python` in elementary/Ubuntu is `python-dev`

```
sudo apt install python-dev
```

For the other stuff let's start to get the essential

```
sudo apt install build-essential
```

Then what you need in the list

```
sudo apt install libwnck22 libwnck-dev libx11-6 libx11-dev libdbus-glib-1-2 libdbus-glib-1-dev libxdamage1 libxdamage-dev libxcomposite1 libxcomposite-dev libxrender1 libxrender-dev python-gtk2 python-gtk2-dev python-xdg
```

I let to you find out how to get `libdesktop-agnostic` installed, too old

ref: https://github.com/p12tic/awn

Comment: So it sounds like this won't work then. I'm sensing that old means no longer works. It looks like the icon pack I was interested in is no longer available anyway.  What is plank?

Comment: As I'm now not going to try this then do I have to undo anything when I did the `./configue` ?

Comment: `configure` just do stuff inside the working dir, even `make` is harmless.... `make install` is the one you run as root because it install the files in the system. Just deleting the directory is enough.

Comment: Plank is the icon bar below - https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uwcag.png